# Требуется ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда мне надо сделать уроки,я всегда прошу у кого-нибудь совета. Есть ли здесь тире перед я?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предложение сложноподчиненное, запятая ставится между частями, дополнительный знак не нужен. Если Вы уберете союз *когда*, предложение стане бессоюзным, тогда для передачи смысловых отношений между частями используется тире. *Мне надо сделать уроки - я прошу совета.*

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении только запятая,здесь нет стилистического подчёркивания, но в принципе в таких случаях возможно и тире вместо запятой: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm§111. 
При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные, реже условные и уступительные, стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире, например: Буде спросит кто о чем– молчи... (Пушкин); Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять (Гоголь); Что она натура честная –это мне ясно... (Тургенев); Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут – я воли своей не отдам(Салтыков-Щедрин); Взгляну ли вдаль, взгляну ли на тебя – и в сердце свет какой-то загорится (Фет); Кто весел –тот смеется, кто хочет – тот добьется, кто ищет – тот всегда найдет! (Лебедев-Кумач)

Answer (score 1):

По правилам пунктуации в СПП здесь нужна запятая